# How to Load Custom Language in Monaco using VueJS/Webpack

Tags: vue.js, monaco-editor, monarch

I've created a custom language using this [tool here](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html).  I don't know what to do to load it to my VueJS app. I tried the following and get no errors, but it also doesn't show seem to work, because in the Monarch tool thing I get blue text on known functions etc, but in my editor I don't. Other languages work as expected.

```js
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const main = path.resolve(__dirname, './src/test/test.ts');

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
        languages: ['javascript', 'typescript', 'python', 'java', 'python', 'json', 'vb'],
        customLanguages: [
          {
            label: 'test',
            entry: main
          }
        ]
      })
    ]
  }
...
```

I made my `.ts` file essentially export a `conf` property with all the variables or whatever that are used in the `tokenizer`. I also exported a `language` property. I'm not totally sure that is the right format.

My `.ts` file essentially looks like:

```js
export const conf = {...}
export const language = {...}
```

I'm not totally sure what to do here. Docs are sparse for custom languages and nothing seems to be working other than I think I at least have the first part of defining the language working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That Webpack plugin isn't actually needed.

Based on the [custom language](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-custom-languages) example, you can register the language at runtime via [`monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider()`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/modules/monaco.languages.html#setMonarchTokensProvider). The second function argument is an instance of [`IMonarchLanguage`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.IMonarchLanguage.html), which matches the language spec in the example you linked.

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import * as monaco from 'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

/**
 * `customLangMonarch` contains the language spec example from
 * https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/monarch.html
 */

// @ts-ignore
import customLangMonarch from '@/custom-lang-monarch'

monaco.languages.register({ id: 'custom' })
monaco.languages.setMonarchTokensProvider('custom', customLangMonarch)

const editor = ref()

onMounted(() => {
  monaco.editor.create(editor.value, {
    language: 'custom',
  })
})
</script>
```

[demo w/Vue CLI](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cli-monaco-editor?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMonacoEditor.vue)

[demo w/Vite](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-monaco-editor?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMonacoEditor.vue)